# Android Studio ejecuto y no aparece nada

Tags: android-studio, botón, genymotion, ejecutar

Hola tengo Android Studio y me está dando toda clase de problemas, no he podido hacer nada. Instalé genymotion e hice los arreglos para ejecutar la aplicación móvil en mi celular, pero no funciona. En mi celular abre la app pero no aparece el botón y en genymotion no aparece la app.

Mi computador sólo tiene 4 GB de Ram y es de 32 bits.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="227dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Y el MainActivity

```
package com.example.jhon.tutorialprogramarapps;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); */

        TextView mitexto = new TextView(this);
        mitexto.setText("Hola alumnos");
        setContentView(mitexto);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cambia tu codigo de tu MainActivity por el siguiente.

```
package com.example.jhon.tutorialprogramarapps;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

         TextView mitexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
         mitexto.setText("Hola alumnos");

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Carlos, me sirvió.

Comment: Hice otra en la que puse 1 botón y nada se ve.package com.example.jhon.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

Comment: Hola, mmm que quieres que tu boton hag?

Comment: Una activity, que me lleve a una parte donde quiero hacer un formulario

Comment: Hola, mejor pon tu pregunta como respondida y crea otra con eso, ya que esa es otra pregunta :D

Comment: Podrías ayudarme aquí.. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195709/no-se-ve-nada-de-nuevo/195712?noredirect=1#comment367359_195712

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**
    this.btnGetRepos=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get_repos);
}
}
```

add xml in res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="389dp"
    android:layout_height="488dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="3dp">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_get_repos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_github_user"
        android:text="Get Repo" />

</LinearLayout>
```