# No se ve nada de nuevo

Tags: android, botón

Estoy intentando usar Android Studio. Puse dos botones y no se ve nada.

CLASE

```
package com.example.jhon.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:maxWidth="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/butCliente"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="110dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="201dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/butTransaccion"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="343dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hay que cambiar algo en el código?

Osea que uno arrastra las cosas y por defecto éstas no se ven? por qué es así este programa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema del API 28 que aun no es estable. He encontrado la solución en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238779/android-studios-3-1-does-not-render-xml-file-due-to-java-class-missing) pregunta. Como está en inglés, voy a poner qué hay que hacer

Cambiar en el build.gradle (Module: app) las líneas que hacen referencia al api 28 por estas (no tienen porqué estar juntas):

```
compileSdkVersion 27 
targetSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Compilar el proyecto y abrir la vista de nuevo

Comment: Los cambio por qué valor? wrap_content ?

Comment: Yo empezaría por quitarlos todos, aunque el más problemático creo que es app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf

Comment: Dejó de funcionar. La vista diseño no está disponible hasta que se haga un build exitoso. Intenté hacer build, pero no sirvió.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: Me dice esto en inglés:  La vista diseño no está disponible hasta que se haga un build exitoso. Y no se ve nada en Design

Comment: ¿Y si haces un build? ¿Qué te dice?

Comment: Lo mismo. Sigue igual.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83004/discussion-between-javi-molla-and-jhon-hernandez).

Comment: hay que cambiar el archivo build.gradle para que apunte al 27

Answer (score 1):

podrias cambiar esto en tu XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/butCliente"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```