# Porque no muestra los componente en la interfaz gráfica del Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola tengo un problema espero me puedan ayudar a resolverlo.
Resulta que instale Android Studio su última version y cuando inserto algun componente como un Boton o EditText no aparece en la vista previa gráfica del Androis Studio como esta en la siguiente foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me fije en los posibles errores que podria ocasionar esto pero no se soluciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que te pasa lo mismo que en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195709/no-se-ve-nada-de-nuevo

Comment: Esto ocurre que la usar ConstraintLayout debes agregar mas atributos a los elementos que se encuentren dentro de este (botones, textviews, edittexts, etc). Por ello si no sabes usar ConstraintLayout cambialo por un LinearLayout y tu problema se resolvera. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Javi Mollá se soluciono el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira, me andaba pasando, tienes 2 soluciones posibles:

1)Ir a build.gradle (module app) y cambiar la versión de la app compat, yo la atrase:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

Esa es la que estoy usando, de esa manera se dibujarían los componentes.

2) Ir a styles.xml y cambiar

```
 style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

por

```
 style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Solo agregue la palabra BASE.

Las diferencias entre estas 2 formas es que la primera te muestra el actionBar, la segunda solo los componentes en la View, espero haberme explicado bien y que te sirva.