# No puedo visualizar los views en el emulador interno de Android Studios

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

[image: Android Studios y GENYMOTION]

Estoy empezando a usar el Android Studios y no se por qué no me muestra las views (o items) en el emulador interno pero en uno externo si.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Comprueba que no te pase lo que en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195709/no-se-ve-nada-de-nuevo

Comment: Al parecer cambiando el tema a Ligth se arregla, lo mostraré por si alguien tiene este mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

[image: Paso 1]

[image: Paso 2]

Con esto ya se me visualizan las views.